# Using put method on Laravel Eloquent Collection will always return an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, lumen

I am using Lumen (Laravel Eloquent ORM) to create a web service to use in conjunction with an app I am working on. I have a Joomla website, which I use Lumen to access resources I need from the db. I'm using Lumen to get these resources into a collection, then return a new JSON object.

To give an overview of the problem, I am creating two Collections:

- Object properties - (Collection 0)
- Associated images to the object (there will be at least 2 images, sometimes more) - (Collection 1)

I want Laravel to return a JSON object for Collection 0 (above), which will include a JSON Array containing the data of Collection 1.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$current = Card::find($id);

//Collection 0
$information = $current -> cardData -> map(function($col) {
    return collect($col -> toArray())
    ->only(['id', 'ccard_cardno', 'ccard_year', 'ccard_catc', 'ccard_catt', 'ccard_issued', 'ccard_valc', 
    'ccard_valtod', 'ccard_valfac', 'ccard_man', 'ccard_info'])
    ->all();
});
//Collection 1
$galleryItems = $current -> galItems -> pluck('ccard');
```

After processing the data as I need, I now add the galleryItems property to my Collection 0:

```
$galleryItems= json_encode($finalGalleryImages);  
$information -> put('galleryImages', $galleryItems);
```

This does work fine, however each collection will be represented as a different object which is not what I want.

What I want is the below:

```
{
    "id": 528,
    "ccard_cardno": "...",
    "ccard_year": "...",
    "ccard_catc": "...",
    "ccard_catt": "...",
    "ccard_issued": "...",
    "ccard_valc": "...",
    "ccard_valtod": "...",
    "ccard_valfac": "...",
    "ccard_man": "...",
    "ccard_info": "...",
    "galleryImages": "[{\"thumb\":\"...",\"image\":\"...\",\"title\":\"...\"},...]"
}
```

(The galleryImages property contains array of photos associated with my object. )

What I actually get is Laravel will create a new object for collection "0":

```
{
  "0": {
    "id": 528,
    "ccard_cardno": "...",
    "ccard_year": "...",
    "ccard_catc": "...",
    "ccard_catt": "...",
    "ccard_issued": "...",
    "ccard_valc": "...",
    "ccard_valtod": "...",
    "ccard_valfac": "...",
    "ccard_man": "...",
    "ccard_info": "...",
  },
  "galleryImages": "[{\"thumb\":\"...",\"image\":\"...\",\"title\":\"...\"},...]"
}
```

The solution to this problem is to call the first() method on $information. In this case the object I put into the collection is excluded! I will get just (galleryImages property is missng)):

```
{
    "id": 528,
    "ccard_cardno": "...",
    "ccard_year": "...",
    "ccard_catc": "...",
    "ccard_catt": "...",
    "ccard_issued": "...",
    "ccard_valc": "...",
    "ccard_valtod": "...",
    "ccard_valfac": "...",
    "ccard_man": "...",
    "ccard_info": "..."
}
```

Here is the object after the information is put() into my collection:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#56 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(11) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(529)
      ["ccard_cardno"]=>
      string(4) "..."
      ["ccard_year"]=>
      string(4) "..."
      ["ccard_catc"]=>
      string(2) "..."
      ["ccard_catt"]=>
      string(10) "..."
      ["ccard_issued"]=>
      string(8) "..."
      ["ccard_valc"]=>
      string(9) "..."
      ["ccard_valtod"]=>
      string(7) "..."
      ["ccard_valfac"]=>
      string(6) "..."
      ["ccard_man"]=>
      string(22) "..."
      ["ccard_info"]=>
      string(337) "..."
    }
    ["galleryImages"]=>
    string(262) "[{"thumb":"...","image":"...","title":".."},...]"
  }
}
```

So it is clear why $response -> json() will now return an Array. My question is, how to I add the values to my Collection 0 using Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using put method like below:

```
$information -> put('galleryImages', $galleryItems);
```

Try using concat method as below:

```
$information ->concat(['galleryImages' => $galleryItems ]);
```

Comment: This does not work unfortunately. It is similar to the behaviour of 'put()' method. I have also tried merge and push methods. In all cases I cannot update the initial Array '0' as shown in the PHP Object Dump above.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by avoiding the response() -> json() method, instead I manually used json_encode on the Arrays.

Here is the code for those interested:

```
  // To avoid Array getting returned, use first()
  $finalCardInformation = $cardInformation -> first();

  $imagesArray = json_encode($finalGalleryImages);

  array_push($finalCardInformation, $imagesArray);

  $jsonResponse = response($finalCardInformation, 200)
  ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

It's not the most elegant, but seems to work fine.